# Null sets on Daniell integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, integration

Can someone help me clarify the definition of null sets related to Daniell integrals. The book I'm using is Introduction to analysis and integration theory by Philips. The definition that I'm provided with is:

A subset $E \subset \Omega$ is said to be $\mu$-null if there is a nondecreasing sequence $\{\sigma_n\}$ in $C_0$ (bounded real valued functions) and a real number $M>0$, such that:

(i)  if $x \in E$ then $\sigma_n(x) \uparrow \infty$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

(ii) $\int \sigma_n d\mu<M$, for $n = 1, 2,...$

Where $\sigma(x)$ denotes an elementary function.

The confusion that I'm having relates to the bound. Does property (ii) simply imply that the sequence of elementary functions are bounded on $\Omega - E$? Would it also imply that it is uniformly bounded on $\Omega - E$?

Answer (score 1):

No, the sequence need not be uniformly bounded outside $E$. You can see this as follows: let $E_2$ be a nonempty null set, and let $E_1$ be a nonempty subset of $E_1$, with $E_1\neq E_2$. Then, there exists a sequence $(\sigma_n)$ as above, which shows that $E_2$ is null. You can also check that this $(\sigma_n)$ shows that $E_1$ is null, but it is not uniformly bounded outside $E_1$: if $x\in E_2\setminus E_1$, then $\sigma_n(x)\to\infty$ and $x\notin E_1$.

Comment: Your set $E$ which seems to defined as $E = (E_2-E_1) \cup E_1$ where both $(E_2-E_1)$ and  $E_1$ are null, hence their union will be null as well. Now if $x \notin E$, or not included in any null set, then would the sequence $\{\sigma_n\}$ be uniformly bounded?

Comment: No, $E$ is $E_1$, and $(\sigma_n)$ is unbounded at a point $x$ outside $E$; $x$ is in $E_1\setminus E_2$ in this case.